# What is the difference between the asadmin purgue message queue command and the imqcmd command

Tags: glassfish, jms

I am new to JMS and have the following question: 
I wish to purgue all the JMS messages which I created in the glassfish JMS queue.
I found two commands to do the same thing

```
 asadmin flush-jmsdest --desttype destType destName
```

&

```
imqcmd purge dst -t destType -n destName
```

What is the difference between these two commands ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `imqcmd purge` is an Oracle server (Operating system) administration command, whereas `asadmin flush-jmsdest` is a Glassfish Application Server administration command. i.e The former is a OS utility while the latter is a Application utility (here application is the Glassfish Application server).
2. `imqcmd purge` returns any value > 0 during an error, whereas `asadmin flush-jmsdest` returns 1 on error.
3. `imqcmd purge` is not Glassfish specific, while `asadmin flush-jmsdest` works only with glassfish Application servers.
4. `imqcmd purge` works only with Oracle servers, while `asadmin flush-jmsdest` is not restricted to Oracle servers.